# Select distinct col1, col2, IF only one record will be the result other wise select col3

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select `value1`, `value2` where `item` = `foo` IF returned is a single distinct record, otherwise I would like to return ALL `year` column where `item` = `foo`, so the user can see the `value` per year.

```
Item year value1 value2
-----------------------
foo  12    32    48
foo  13    32    50
foo  14    32    50
foo  15    33    48
foo  16    33    48
foo  17    33    48
fo3  13    38    42
fo3  14    34    44
fo4  15    36    46
fo5  16    37    48
```

This is how I currently select a distinct column, but as you can tell by my question, this query is not complex enough for what I need to do.

```
SELECT distinct value1, value2
FROM MyTable
WHERE item = 'foo'
```

By the current table my desired result would be the results of `year` where `item` = `foo`, as there is more than 1 distinct result.

Eg: `12 13 14 15 16 17`

Yet if my table was to look like this below, where there is only one disatinc `value1` `value2` for `item` = `foo` I would like only `value1` `value2` returned

```
Item year value1 value2
    -----------------------
    foo  12    32    50
    foo  13    32    50
    foo  14    32    50
    foo  15    32    50
    foo  16    32    50
    foo  17    32    50
    fo3  13    38    42
    fo3  14    34    44
    fo4  15    36    46
    fo5  16    37    48
```

Desired result

`32 50`

EXAMPLE LOGIC (will not work as is)

```
SELECT value1, value2
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE item = 'foo'
 GROUP BY value1, value2 IF count = 1 ELSE 
SELECT year From MyTable WHERE item = 'foo';
```

Comment: _this query is not complex enough_ huh?

Comment: @hjpotter92 correct, my current query is only a basic select distinct statement.

Comment: I think that means "this query might be too complex for me to actually put an effort into solving..."

Comment: @SS781 not true. currently I count the results in php and then do another SQL call if required. So it's not a case of can't bothered, it's a case of not knowing. there is no other question on here like this.

Comment: what result you want get ? can you edit and put wished result ?

Comment: @echo_Me i've edited my question with a desired result example based on both conditions.

Comment: @mellamokb correct, the question is on how to do that within SQL, a apposed to multiple SQL queries and PHP counts.

Comment: you need an if statement, so looks like stored procedure would be way to go, I don't see any other way...

Comment: Why do you need a pure sql solution if you can combine php logic to achieve your desired results?

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
 SELECT year,value1, value2
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE item = 'foo'
 GROUP BY value1, value2
```

EDIT:

```
 SELECT year,value1, value2, count(*)
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE item = 'foo'
 GROUP BY value1, value2 
 HAVING count(*)=1
```

Comment: thanks, This will return the distinct records regardless of results returned. I've edited my question with some example logic on what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks, That looks like it might work - but what If more than one record is found?

Comment: so the year is your problem ? if you have one result or more result its up to you to select year or not,

Comment: you can select year in first query i writed and even it return one or many results you have the year , and its up to you if you use it or not

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that through the use of a prepared statement:

```
SET @item = 'foo'; -- set to 'fo3' for a proof of the expected behaviour

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value1, value2)
    INTO @count
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE item = @item;

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT ', IF(@count = 1, 'value1, value2', 'year'),
                    ' FROM MyTable WHERE item = \'', @item, '\'');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

DEMO @ **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0005/1)**

Answer (score -1):

SELECT 'count_one' as rec_cnt, year,value1, value2, count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE item = 'foo' GROUP BY value1, value2 HAVING count(*)=1

Union

SELECT 'count_many' as rec_cnt, year,value1, value2, count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE item = 'foo' GROUP BY value1, value2 HAVING count(*)>1